# How to display Int to screen/label SWIFT

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am not sure how to display an int to the screen?

this is what i've tried:

```
@IBOutlet weak var Button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var someLabel: UILabel!
var someVar = 0

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    someVar = someVar + 1  
    someLabel.text = (String)someVar
}
```

I have linked up the button and label to the view controller.

Thanks, sorry for the noob question.

Comment: try using a format like  someLabel.text = String(format : "%d",someVar)

Comment: how would you write `textLabel.text = String(myArray[indexPath.row])`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is not a valid type cast in Swift.

```
(String)someVar
```

If String was a valid subtype of Int, you could downcast with the "as" operator, but it isn't.

In this case, you want to initialize a new String passing the Int as an argument.

```
someLabel.text = String(someVar)
```

Comment: how would you write `textLabel.text = String(myArray[indexPath.row])`

Answer (score 7):

Try using the following,

```
someLabel.text = "\(someVar)"
```

Comment: how would you write `textLabel.text = String(myArray[indexPath.row])`

Answer (score 4):

you can do something like this:

```
someLabel.text = NSString(format:"%d", someVar)
```

Comment: There is no difference between %d and %i in a print format string.

Comment: how would you write `textLabel.text = String(myArray[indexPath.row])`

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
someLabel.text = "\(someVar)"
```

Yeah

```
someLabel.text = String(someVar)
```

Go through this doc https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html

Comment: Thank you someLabel.text = "\(someVar)" was perfect too.

Comment: also, i went through the document briefly before hand, but didn't look hard enough. thanks again.

Comment: how would you write `textLabel.text = String(myArray[indexPath.row])`

Comment: you can do it like this textLabel.text = String(describing: myArray[indexPath.row])